# Is there a way to avoid all the undefined fields when creating a new object with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the type `Player`:

```
type Player = {
  id: Scalars['ID'];
  name: Scalars["String"];
  age: Scalars["Int"];
  description?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>;
  __typename?: "Player";
  // ... and dozens and dozens of other fields here ...
};
```

Now I need to add a **new** `Player` in an existing array:

```
let players: Player[] = [];

players = [...players, newPlayer()]

function newPlayer() {
  return {
    id: newID(),
    name: undefined,
    age: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    // ... and so on dozens and dozens ...
  }
}
```

I only need to set a `newID()` in the new Player. All other field are useless to me in this situation.

Is there a way to avoid all the `undefined` fields in `newPlayer()`?

Comment: If you type them as optional typescript won't complain if you don't put them.

Comment: I cannot change the type.

Comment: If you make a Player `class` you can give all those fields default values.

Comment: If you want to keep the type unchanged, then omitting the fields would mean it's a different type. Types are not only about values, they're also about what fields exist, even if their value is empty. Currently your type says these fields must exist to match this type.

Comment: @Kokodoko, can you write an example?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpg47N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
let players: Player[] = [];

players = [...players, newPlayer()]

function newPlayer(): Player {
  return {
    id: newID(),
  } as Player;
}
```

just by casting type to Player, you don't need to set all unnecessary properties. and the syntax to access Player properties are valid.

```
console.log(players[0].id, players[0].name);
```

Comment: But now you can also leave out properties that ARE required, in this case the ID! If you use `as` you tell typescript to ignore type information!

Answer (score 1):

> All other field are useless to me in this situation.

If the fields are optional, then just set the type accordingly and set a proper return type to your function

```js
type Player = {
  id: Scalars['ID'];
  name?: Scalars["String"];
  age?: Scalars["Int"];
  // ...
};

function newPlayer(): Player {
```

There is no reason to use typescript if you define some types but want to use something different in your code. If you want to actually only return a subset of fields from your `newPlayer` function and have a proper typing for it, you can use [`Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

```js
function newPlayer(): Pick<Player, 'id'> {
```